# Could not load information for project X after update codegeneration 6.0.9

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, nuget

I'm developing a .NET Core project. Yesterday, `Web.CodeGeneration` was updated automatically. After the update, I get an error when I try to add new view to my project:

> "Scaffolding Failed"
> "Could not load information for project X"

I tried to remove and re-install all nuget packages again, and I checked package versions and all of them are 6.0.9 so, same version.

I tried to create a new project to test "add view", but when I install Entity Framework Core packages with `web.codegeneration` in the test, project, I again get the same error.

How to fix it?

Comment: yes i have 4 project that are for data access, busines, entity and ui

Comment: Try to update all related NuGet packages in all projects to v6.0.9. I have application targeting .NET 6.0, **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore** (6.0.9), **Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design** (6.0.9), Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools (6.0.9) and adding a new view without a problem.

Comment: thanks your answer. i tried but everything is same. i said, all packages are same version (6.0.9). i reduced codegeneration version to 6.0.8 and copy project to work on different pc and  disconneceted internet. project worked. until i find a solution, i never connect internet new pc :)

Answer (score 5):

Unload all your class libraries/other projects except for your web application then try re-adding any scaffolded items. This is the current workaround that works on my end, at least until this bug gets fixed.

**Update:**

Bug is patched with the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design 6.0.10

Comment: thanks for your answer. this way worked. it should be a bug but until they fix it i think best way is your solution.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT - Fixed in 6.0.10, if you are experiencing this issue make sure you update the packages.

The issue has been [reported](https://github.com/dotnet/Scaffolding/issues/2019) and is a bug in the scaffolding code.

The suggested workaround is to scaffold in a new solution/project with the same name(s) and then copy the files over:

> Make new project with same solution and project name and add DB context and
> other necessary thing than scaffold then the new added files add in the
> main  project you are making, now you are good to go.

Unloading the linked projects as suggested by others works, provided you don't have your models in separate class projects.

Otherwise we will have to wait

Comment: Thank you! I thought I was going mad. Good temporary solution too.

Comment: I updated to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design 6.0.10 but every time I run the scaffolding tool it downgrades it back to 6.0.9

Comment: I ended up doing the workaround of creating a new project with the same name and that worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Remove all project references in the project you are working on, then you won't get error. After adding Areas etc. you can again add project references

Answer (score 1):

If you create references to other projects, the error returns. Importing the libraries works, but if you reference them it gives an error

Comment: No need to remove the project reference. Just unload the referenced projects in your solution and adding scaffolded items will work with no error

Comment: I mean, I make a new project and download the class libraries. When I make references from the new web project to the libraries I download it gives me an error. O tengo que hacer otra?

Comment: Yes, you can reference the class library project then unload it to temporarily avoid the scaffolding error. With this, you can still use your class libraries. Just reload the project if you need to modify them. We still need to wait until this bug gets patched.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't actually an answer, but I'm too new to leave a comment. I just wanted to pass along some information that I found useful.
I was having an issue scaffolding my MVC Controller, with views, when my Library was unloaded, even though I kept the reference.  This bug is also being discussed on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/Scaffolding/issues/2019), and Deepak Joy Jose uploaded this video showing the workaround: [Scaffolding Workaround](https://youtu.be/VFq4aeP0XWQ)  It's for identity scaffolding issues, but the same logic applies to controllers.  It's a long workaround, but it did work for my issue.