# I can't add view in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Using ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC, I'm attempting to create a web project with an n-tier architecture. I encounter the following issue when attempting to add a view from the Controller. After a few hours of investigation, I was unable to come up with a solution; therefore, I would appreciate your assistance.

Error message:

> *There was an error running the selected code generator:  'Scaffolding failed. Could not load information for project
> C:\Users\PC\source\repos\BlogProject\BusinessLayer\BusinessLayer.csproj'*

Comment: Check this temporary solution: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/73760075/6630084](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73760075/6630084)

Comment: A view is just a text file with a .cshtml extension. If you're not worried about missing out on the scaffolding feature, just manually add a .cshtml file to your folder and you're good to start editing.

Comment: Do you mean when you right click the action name in controller and select `Add View...`, The project will report this error?

Comment: Yes, I am attempting to add exactly as you suggested. @XinranShen

Comment: @salihakdogan， Then it still can't create .cshtml file and report the error ?

Comment: @XinranShen, I solved the error temporarily and i specified the method in my answer below.

Comment: @salihakdogan, Yes i see it. But it seems to be a bug, a lot of people have had this problem recently

Comment: @XinranShen, I hope the bug will be resolved as soon as possible. Doing everything manually is really annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@salihakdogan

[image]

This Issue relates the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` package. It often caused by using 6.0.9 version, 6.0.8 version and 6.0.0 version.

It is a [know Issue](https://github.com/dotnet/Scaffolding/issues/2019), You can follow this github issue to wait for the response from Microsoft.

Or you can try to the following methods:

**Method 1:**

1. Remove the Database class library reference from the MVC project
2. According to the models in the Database class library, create models
   (use the same name) in the MVC projects.
3. In MVC projects, you can use Scaffold to add the generate pages with
   the new created models.
4. Remove the models from the MVC project and re-add the Database class
   library project reference. [Note] You need to change the model
   reference in the generated page.

**Method 2**:

You can also create a new project which contains the MVC and Database models(put them in the same project), then generate the page using Scaffolded, after that you can copy the generated page to the original/main project.

**Method 3**

Try to downgrade the Asp.net 6 application to Asp.net 5(remember to downgrade the relates package, especially the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design package), then use Scaffold to generate the related views, after that migration the application from Asp.net 5 to Asp.net 6.

Comment: I tried all the methods but it didn't work. I solved the error temporarily and i specified the method in my answer above.

Comment: sorry about that ,Maybe we can only wait for the response from Visual studio team.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved the bug temporarily, Within the View folder, I made a category folder (my controller's name). Index.cshtml was manually inserted to the category folder. I believe there is a general issue with nuget packages.