# Scaffolding failed Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

"There was an error running the selected code generator: Scaffolding failed. Could not load information for project
C:Users...\ARSTEST.csproj"
The message shows up when I try to make a razor view
Also this: To see more information, enable tracing by setting environment variable 'codegen_trace' = 1.
I'm a beginner and I don't know about these errors

Comment: If you build your solution, does the project ARSTEST build? If not, fix the errors prior to scaffolding.

Comment: Check [https://stackoverflow.com/q/73757296/6630084](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73757296/6630084)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.